# Can DROP or TRUNCATE statements successfully execute in any scenario if there are no spaces to their right?

Tags: mariadb

Are there *any* scenarios in which the `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` statements can successfully execute when either of those commands are not immediately followed by a space?

Another way to phrase this question: does the MariaDB internal parser recognize and therefore will execute the `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` statements if there is any other character besides space immediately after those statement names?

We're just working on our database error log where we can remove entries that match error messages. An older function triggered a security stop when an error contained the string "Data truncated for column".

Comment: It seems like `TABLE` (or maybe some other object type) must follow them.  Do you have any more clues?

Comment: Drop table needs at least a table name but allows for example comments see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-table/ truncate has similar option but much less than DROP https://mariadb.com/kb/en/truncate-table/

Comment: The list of possible inter-token delimiters in MariaDB is tiny - space, tabular, linebreak, parenthesis, quote symbols, some another special symbols... if there is no such symbol then the literal is parsed as solid one, the keyword is not distinguished correctly, and syntax error is detected. So when DROP/TRUNCATE keyword and the table name are linked together then the query won't be parsed correctly, and it will fail.

Comment: *We're just working on our database error log where we can remove entries that match error messages. An older function triggered a security stop when an error contained the string "Data truncated for column".* - provide a sample (2-3 values) with received and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One example is inline comments:

```
TRUNCATE/* hello */tablename;
DROP/* hello */TABLE tablename;
```

You can also use "--" and have the commands over two lines:

```
TRUNCATE--
tablename;
DROP--
TABLE tablename;
```

And speaking of multiple lines, assuming you don't count line-break as space, then this would also satisfy the criteria in your question:

```
TRUNCATE
tablename;
DROP
TABLE tablename;
```